# Submitting a marketplace enterprise app

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We are building a marketplace app. I have used DOMAIN_INSTALLABLE in manifest. From what I understand all apps are to be submitted in chrome webstore.

If our app is approved, will it show up in http://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/search?categoryId=25&orderBy=RATING&type=INSTALLABLE ?

Or do we need to do something else to make sure our app is listed on enterprise marketplace and (not in) chrome webstore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer to that.

http://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/ is old version and deprecated.

Chrome webstore is the new single marketplace store.

reference: [Still old v1 Google Apps Market Place listing prevails, although new version approved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26929581/still-old-v1-google-apps-market-place-listing-prevails-although-new-version-app)

Answer (score 0):

If you include domain installable in the manifest, that isn't going to show up in the chrome webstore except while it is pending approval.

If you search "Google apps marketplace" that is where it shows up. Google apps marketplace and the chrome webstore are two different places even though they use the same developer console.